# Tailwind workframe background class doesnt work

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm getting started with tailwind and some background colors just doesn't work. My body code is like this:

```
<body class = "w-screen h-screen bg-gradient-to-br from-zinc-950 to-zinc-900">
    <section class = "w-[1100px] h-[650px] bg-black">
        <h1 class = "font-sans text-3xl text-white">Faça seu Login</h1>
    </section>
</body>
```

if I change the body class to: `<body class = "w-screen h-screen bg-gradient-to-br from-zinc-900 to-zinc-800">` the background just goes all white.

I've tried other colors like emerald, orange, red, blue, even tried without the gradient class and using a solid color only but bothing works.

The most strange thing is that using the same code in tailwind play platform, it works great.

It's probably a very easy problme to fix, but I just don't know what is happening... Can someone help?

```
<body class = "w-screen h-screen bg-gradient-to-br from-zinc-950 to-zinc-900">
    <section class = "w-[1100px] h-[650px] bg-black">
        <h1 class = "font-sans text-3xl text-white">Faça seu Login</h1>
    </section>
</body>
```